# Woocommerce - Add extra form fields to single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm using Woocommerce and on the single product page I'd like to display some custom form fields in addition to the default "quantity" field.

These form fields are simple: ***first_name***, ***last_name***, ***email***, and ***phone***. I would like to collect this information when the user purchaes the product.

I tried using a plugin first: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-product-options/. This allowed me to add the fields but the labels were not displayed correctly so I don't wish to use this one.

Second, the only code examples I've found are for adding custom product fields in the backend and the following code which doesn't output a textfield:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 0 );

function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;
    echo "<div class='prod-code'>Product Code: ";
    $text= get_post_meta('_text_field', $post->ID);
    echo "</div>";
    return true;
}
```

How can I add the extra form fields to the single product page?

Comment: You could try [WooCommerce Product Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: Thanks. This works for an answer too. Do you know how to do this through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [WooCommerce Product Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/) plugin as a solution for this.